# How is UITextChecker availableLanguages order determined?

Tags: ios

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextChecker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UITextChecker/availableLanguages) for the availableLanguages method of UITextChecker states that:

> The languages represented by the strings in the returned array are in
>   user-preference order.

Exactly where does the user set his preferred language? Settings > General > Language & Region does not change the returned list of languages... so what does?

For example, printing available languages:

```
println(UITextChecker.availableLanguages())
```

shows me:

```
[en_CA, da_DK, en_IN, en_US, nl_NL, en_AU, fr_FR, pt_PT, en_GB, es_ES, sv_SE, ru_RU, de_DE, tr_TR, it_IT, pt_BR]
```

Apparently the preferred language on my iPhone is set to "en_CA" which is English->Canada. I would expect "en_US" to be first in the array since I live in the United States. How can I make changes so that en_US is first?